# Javascript to remove selected items from cart

Tags: javascript, function, cart

This function below allows a user to click on a menu item and have it displayed in a cart. I now want to add some code to give user access to delete items from the cart.
Any suggestions how to do that?

```
function addToCart(H,D,P){
    document.getElementById('Cart').innerHTML += 
    document.getElementById(H).innerText + ' ' + 
    document.getElementById(D).innerText + '<br>' + '<br>'
    document.getElementById('Price').innerText = 
    Number(document.getElementById('Price').innerText) +
    Number(document.getElementById(P).innerText)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a class name to every element, for example creating something like

```
let count=0

function addToCart(H,D,P){
    count= count+1
    let classnameH="myclassH"+count;
    let classnameD="myclassD"+count;
    let classnameP="myclassP"+count;
    document.getElementById('Cart').innerHTML += 
    document.getElementById(H).innerText + ' ' + 
    document.getElementById(D).innerText + '<br>' + '<br>'
    document.getElementById('Price').innerText = 
    Number(document.getElementById('Price').innerText) +
    Number(document.getElementById(P).innerText)
    document.getElementById(H).classList.add(classnameH);
    document.getElementById(D).classList.add(classnameD);
    document.getElementById(P).classList.add(classnameP);
}

function removeItem(H,D,P){
    document.getElementsByClassName(H)[0].remove();
    document.getElementsByClassName(D)[0].remove();
    document.getElementsByClassName(P)[0].remove();

}
```